# jQuery animate within animate callback works only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have two pagination links which trigger a jQuery animation.

A callback function on the animation triggers a second animation.

This works fine, however, it only works the first time the function is called.

Each time after, the first of the 2 animations works and the second one does not, it merely changes the CSS without the effect.

I'm racking my brain here, to no effect (pun intended).

```
function switchItem(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // If not current piece
    if($(this).hasClass('light')) {

        /*  VARIABLES */
        var container = $('.portfolio footer .portfolio_content');
        var link = $(this).attr('id');
        var newItem = $(this).html();


        /*===================================================
        *   This is the Key part here
        ===================================================*/

            /* FIRST ANIMATION */

            container.animate({
                'right':'-100%'
            }, 300, 'swing',

            // Callback Function
            function() {

                $(this).html('').css({'left':'-100%'});

                $.get('inc/portfolio/'+link+'.php', function(data) {

                    container.html(data);

                    /* SECOND ANIMATION */

                    container.animate({
                        'left':'0%'
                    }, 300, 'swing');

                });
            });     
    }
}
```

Here is the demonstration: http://eoghanoloughlin.com/my_site/#portfolio

Comment: is it possible that this is because you put the animation into the @get@ function instead of directly in the callback function? try moving the animate outside the get, but within the callback.

Comment: Why are you animating the right and left? I think you need to pick on and stick with it. The right and left css may be conflicting. * in the two container.animate() calls...

Comment: you were right they were conflicting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See working sample here, your left is conflicting with your first right -100% animation and at the end if you don't reset the right then it will conflict with your second left animation

http://jsfiddle.net/PAdr3/2/

reset left before animating

```
container.css('left', 'auto');
```

and reset right when complete

```
container.animate({
     'left':'0%'
 }, 300, 'swing', function() {
    $(this).css('right', 'auto');

 });
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was the fix I needed.

Comment: I do have a further question, if anybody sees this. You may notice during animation in the demo that sometimes part of the image gets left behind for a split second. Does anybody know of a quick fix for that issue?

Comment: when does this happen? do you see it on fiddle?

Comment: Check the demo again. I changed the animation because of this glitch I'm referring to but I've put the older version back up to show you. When you click the lighter shaded pagination, it triggers that animation. I'm on a very  very slow internet connection here but I'm pretty sure even on a slow connection it will still do it. I think it might be something to do with the frame rate or something.  
It doesn't happen every time, so you might have to click it a few times.

Comment: sorry i don't see any glitch, my computer is pretty fast though. Things that might cause something like what you describe - on a slow computer you might see a frame of your div sliding back to position left even when the animation speed is at 0. Your $.get could be causing this since you are on a slow connection, what you can try is moving all of the animation in the $.get success function

Answer (score 0):

I think that the animate function does not string until the first animate is ready. The docs say:

> If supplied, the complete callback function is fired once the
>   animation is complete. This can be     useful for stringing different
>   animations together in sequence.

Something like this might work:

```
function switchItem(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // If not current piece
    if($(this).hasClass('light')) {
        /*  VARIABLES */
        var container = $('.portfolio footer .portfolio_content');
        var link = $(this).attr('id');
        var newItem = $(this).html();

        /*===================================================
        *   This is the Key part here
        ===================================================*/
            /* FIRST ANIMATION */
            container.animate({
                'right':'-100%'
            }, 300, 'swing',
            // Callback Function
            function() {
                $(this).html('').css({'left':'-100%'});
                $.get('inc/portfolio/'+link+'.php', function(data) {
                    container.html(data);
                });
            }).complete(
                /* SECOND ANIMATION */
                container.animate({
                    'left':'0%'
                }, 300, 'swing');
            );     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you replace the html in a page with new content, it will not automatically add listeners or other jquery enhancements that are added via javascript.

I suspect you need to apply these again after you put the content you fetched with $.get into the page.

Another alternative, is to add all the content in one load, but make the second page hidden.  This is probably a nicer alternative than using $.get